# Automated warning for questions about something that "does not work"

Tags: feature-request, warning, question-restrictions

All too often on various SE sites I see questions which share a common flaw: the OP states that his contraption *does not work*, without any useful information about the issue. A comment asking for clarification usually appears shortly after the question is posted, after which the question is typically put on hold as unclear, unless the OP is quick enough to provide a useful description of their problem.

I wonder if it's possible to warn well-meaning users in advance, so they don't have to rush against the close votes piling up, by showing them a warning message while they're writing their question, e.g.

> Note that *does not work* is not a useful problem statement. Please explain what behavior **you have observed** and what you **expected to see**.

This way, users who strive to write a good question will get the warning before their experience is spoiled by downvotes / close vote / sarcastic comments. Those who don't care will of course post anyway, but at least I'll spend less time dealing with them, since there will be no need to ask for clarification, wait, check again and vote to close: I'll know I can vote to close directly.

When I started writing this question I was going to suggest imposing a restriction to *does not work* questions, like the one we have for the word *problem*. By now, I don't think it's a good idea anymore. A warning will improve the experience for well-meaning users (which is the most important part) without really restricting anyone.

Comment: Hmm, have you seen this anywhere other than SO? I'm thinking meta.SO would've been a better venue for this question.

Comment: Yeah - just SO where, I suspect, if questions about issues with inadequate research/description/debugging were restricted, there would be next-to-no questions allowed:(

Comment: @M.A.R. Actually, I see plenty of questions like that on hardware-oriented sites like Electronics, Raspberry Pi and Arduino, not so much on SO.